# semanage command not working in RHEL 8 on AWS

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to reconfigure the default port `apache` uses on `RedHat Enterprise Linux 8` by usine the `semanage` command. When I try to run the `semanage` command, I get the following error:

```
-bash: semanage: command not found
```

I have the following dependancies installed:

```
policycoreutils
policycoreutils-python
```

These are the only 2 dependancies that should be required for this to work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get `semanage` to work?

Alternatively, does anyone have a different way to re-configure `apache` to use a different default port like `8080`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`policycoreutils-python-utils` is the right package and contains semanage.
A handy trick to ensure the right packages are installed is to call yum with the binary you want to install:

```
yum install /usr/sbin/semanage
```

That way you get semanage plus all necessary deps.

But back to your problem: The package `policycoreutils-python` does not exist. So either that is a typo and you are talking about `policycoreutils-python-utils` or something else is going on.

You might want to call semanage with the full path of /usr/sbin/semanage to make sure a messed up PATH variable does not interfere.

Comment: Thanks @ixs. That did the trick.